# MediaStream reference not removed / why does my webcam stay busy?

Tags: getusermedia, navigator, mediastream

#### Background / Issue

Using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)` I can obtain a MediaStream object for various devices, amongst them webcam and microphone, allowing you to do whatever you want with the data that comes through.

The method `getUserMedia` returns a `Promise` which resolve to a media stream or rejects if there is no stream available for the given constraints (video, audio etc.) If I do obtain a stream object BUT don't save any reference to the MediaStream - I understand that the garbage collector should remove it.

What I've observed is that the stream is not removed - if I obtain a stream for the webcam for example, it keeps being busy even though I have no reference left to the stream.

#### Questions

1. Where is the MediaStream object stored if I don't save a reference to it?
2. Why is it not removed by the garbage collector?
3. Why does my webcam stay busy?

Comment: What browser? With [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/qz7qh9h7/) my camera light goes out after ~10 seconds in both Firefox and Chrome. Care to include some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MediaStream API](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams) requires you to stop each track contained in the MediaStream instance that you obtained. Until you do so, the media capture will keep going.

```js
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
  })
  .then(function (stream) {
    console.log('got stream with id ' + stream.id)
    stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) { track.stop() })
    // WebCam will not be busy anymore
  })
  .catch(function (reason) {
    console.error('capture failed ' + reason)
  })
```

Comment: I guess that when I had this problem, there was some underlying mechanism in the HTML video framework (videojs) I was using that was messing up amount of times getUserMedia was called. Having that said, your post answered the question :)